# Openshift 3 router error

Tags: openshift

I have a pod that is active and a route setup, however, the website does not appear to work.

oc status returns the following error

```
Errors:
  * route/php is routing traffic to svc/php, but either the administrator has not installed a router or the router is not selecting this route.
```

What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What OpenShift cluster is this? OpenShift Online? Your own you setup or something like MiniShift? Have you used ``oc rsh`` or web console to get a terminal in the container and verified using ``curl`` that your application is accepting requests on ``$HOSTNAME:8080``? The latter will establish that your application is at least working first.

Comment: If you're experiencing this on starter-us-west-2 OpenShift Online cluster right now, it's most probably a common problem. I've recreated my project on starter-ca-central-1 and it works well.

Comment: Indeed the problem appears to have been resolved